# Why does Google Calendar API insert my event 4 hours earlier than the date/time that I've given it using Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-calendar-api, mern, utc

I have finally got the google calendar api to insert events into my calendar with Node.js, but the event is inserted 4 hours earlier than the start time that I've given it.

Here's what I've done to get it to insert. In this example:
the date variable is '2022-05-18' and
the time variable is '17:18' and
then when I console.log the apptDate variable, the output is 2022-05-18T17:18:00.000Z

but the event is inserted in my calendar on 2022-05-18 at 13:18.

```
export const insertGoogleCalendarEvent = async (req, res)=> {
    try{
    const {firstName, lastName, date, time, duration} = req.body

    const apptDate = new Date(`${date}T${time}:00.000Z`).toISOString()

    const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.events']
    const GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY
    const GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL = process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL
    const GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER = process.env.GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER
    const GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID = process.env.GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID

    let endDateTime = ''
    if (duration === '60') {
        let newDate = new Date(apptDate)
        newDate.setHours(newDate.getHours() + 1)
        endDateTime = newDate.toISOString()
    } else if (duration === '75') {
        let newDate = new Date(apptDate)
        newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + 75)
        endDateTime = newDate.toISOString()
    } else if (duration === '90') {
        let newDate = new Date(apptDate)
        newDate.setMinutes(newDate.getMinutes() + 90)
        endDateTime = newDate.toISOString()
    }

    const event = {
        'summary': `${firstName} ${lastName}`,
        'start': {
            'dateTime': `${apptDate}`,
            'timeZone': 'Canada/Eastern'
        },
        'end': {
            'dateTime': `${endDateTime}`,
            'timeZone': 'Canada/Eastern'
        }
    }

    const jwtClient = new google.auth.JWT(
        GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
        null,
        GOOGLE_PRIVATE_KEY,
        SCOPES
    )

    const calendar = google.calendar({
        version: 'v3',
        project: GOOGLE_PROJECT_NUMBER,
        auth: jwtClient
    })

    
        calendar.events.insert({
            calendarId: GOOGLE_CALENDAR_ID,
            resource: event,
        }, {
            function (err, event) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log('this is an error', err)
                    return
                }
                console.log('Event created:', event.htmlLink);
            }
        })
    } catch {
        console.log('error')
    }
}
```

Comment: What timezone are you in? Sounds like a UTC to local time zone conversion is happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One reason could be the `.00Z` part at the end of your `appDate` variable as it refers to the `UTC` time zone (Z means UTC or Zulu time). Try to set the needed timezone by using the format `-04:00` (Canada/Eastern) at the end.

### Example

```
const apptDate = new Date(`${date}T${time}:00-04:00`).toISOString()
```

## Update

After reviewing the problem again, I think the API adjusted the date and time you have set in the `apptDate` variable (`.000Z`, UTC) to the timezone you specified in the `timeZone` option. In this case, it's `Canada/Eastern`, UTC-4 hours, so it removed 4 hours from what you have set.

The `dateTime` documentation says

> The time, as a combined date-time value (formatted according to
> RFC3339). A time zone offset is required unless a time zone is
> explicitly specified in timeZone.

So a cleaner approach would be to use the `apptDate` as it is (UTC), without the `timeZone` option.

### Example

```
const apptDate = new Date(`${date}T${time}:00.000Z`).toISOString()

...

'start': {
        'dateTime': `${apptDate}`
    },
    'end': {
        'dateTime': `${endDateTime}`
    }
```

### More information

[Calendar API documentation](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/insert)

Comment: Thanks Tamas! This was the issue. I'm still struggling to wrap my head around dates/times with javascript - seems like a confusing subject. I appreciate the help :)

Comment: Of course! I've updated the answer with a more accurate explanation.